# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature. [7017]

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am using typescript and am seeing the following error

> [ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature. [7017]

```
const store = {};
setItem: jest.fn((key, value) => {
    store[key] = value.toString();
})
```

I can fix it by setting the store to any like so

```
const store: any = {};
```

but I would like to type it, but can't figure out how to do this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, what kind of type do you want it to have? If it's just a simple key-value pair then this will suffice:

```
type Dict = { [key: string]: string };

const store: Dict = {};

store['foo'] = 'bar';
```

Edit (June of 2019)

Typescript also has a built-in type called [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) which is meant for this use case - *as long as your type is not supposed to have any predefined keys!*

```
const store: Record<string, string> = {};

store.foo = 'bar';
```

Comment: thanks, that does it. I was close, but I had `type StoreType { key: string;}`. Why do you need to declare string twice?

Comment: @peterflanagan, since you're trying to type an object with dynamic keys you have to tell the compiler both the type of the key itself `[key: string]` and then the type of the value that will be associated with the key - `string` in this case.

Comment: ok, cool, that makes sense. And what if it could be a string or a number? `type Dict = { [key: string]: string | number };` ?

Comment: @peterflanagan, the type of a dynamic key can be either `string` or `number`, yes. The value can be whatever you want/need.